# To save app data in android

Tags: android

I have developed an app that is to save daily income and outcome. Those income and outcome will be update every time. If my phone is break down, my app's data will be lost? How should I do to save income and output record.

Comment: What does "if my phone breaks down mean"

Comment: I mean my phone installed this app and my phone need to do factory reset.

Comment: You should use Restful webservice which can store the data as a backup in the server so can fetch data if your phone got break down in any case.

Comment: Why not connect it with Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a external storage on your phone, such as an SD card, you could save your data to a SQLite database located here, so you're not losing you data even if you do a factory reset. Most devices won't never delete your SD Card data during a factory reset, some other may ask you if you want to.

Any information android would by default keep in the data folder, except non critical stuff (remembering user's login, personal settings...) should be saved in the external directory.

To write to the external storage, you must request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your Manifest, and while creating the database, call an overloaded method that allows you to specify its location.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload (Post by using php) details to website database by using json
   api.
2. Or save data (encrypted text or other file) in memory card.
3. Or use sqlite technology.